# .NET MAUI Swipeview Text is cut off

Tags: user-interface, maui, .net-maui

I don't know what's causing the text in the swipeview item to be cut off. I've only ran this on Android. Any ideas out there? I swear it was working just a few hours ago...

I've combed through the documentation and there're no other properties on the swipeview that pertain to the text except Text=""

[image: swipeview text cut off]

Here's the XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SwipeView">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkSeaGreen" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#508350" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<Page.Behaviors>
    <mct:StatusBarBehavior
        StatusBarColor="Beige"
        StatusBarStyle="DarkContent" />
</Page.Behaviors>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    >
        <CollectionView.EmptyView>
            <StackLayout Padding="50">
                <Label TextColor="White"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       Text="NO DATA"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </CollectionView.EmptyView>

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:BudgetDisplay">
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">
                        <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="LightPink" Text="Delete" />
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <Grid Margin="5,3,5,3" Padding="0,5,0,0" ColumnDefinitions="10,*,*,*,*,100" RowDefinitions="*,*" BackgroundColor="#CFE2CF">
                    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:d}'}"/>
                    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Payee}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat='{0:c}'}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LineBalance, StringFormat='{0:c}'}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Catagory}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Add HeightRequest.  `<Grid HeightRequest="60" ...>`. [Speculation] Maybe a bug in Maui's layout logic, where at first it thinks the itemtemplate is one label-line tall, and then later fixes it to the correct height (but doesn't correct the swipe item height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to add the `HeightRequest` property to the `SwipeView` and `Grid` like below. I tested it and it worked as expected. It looks like a potential issue on Android, as Steve suggested, you can raise a new issue via [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).

```
   <SwipeView HeightRequest="60">
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">
                        <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="LightPink" Text="Delete" />
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                   <Grid HeightRequest="60" Margin="5,3,5,3" Padding="0,5,0,0" ColumnDefinitions="10,*,*,*,*,100" RowDefinitions="*,*" BackgroundColor="#CFE2CF">
                    
                   </Grid>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
   </SwipeView>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue with the swipeview, but now the top and bottom border around each cell is gone. I can't seem to get it back with different values for both HeightRequests.

Comment: @XJonOneX, good catch! To make sure the border is not gone, just wrap the `Grid` with a `VerticalStackLayout`. I updated my answer, you can try it.

Comment: @alexandar-may-msft Thank you for your assistance with this. I added the VerticalStackLayout like you suggested. That brought back the top portion of my selection border, but the bottom portion doesn't change with the selection. Also, now when I start to swipe the Grid, the border immediately shifts to the right instead of staying in place like the image shows in my original post.